# UISwitch broken in simulator in Xcode 9.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, uiswitch

I just updated to Xcode 9.3 and can't activate `UISwitch`es anymore. It works on a device, but not in the simulator. Also, I tried it with a fresh project, still nothing. Also I tried 'Erase all content and settings' in simulator, nothing.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: It works for me without a problem, both manually and programmatically. Can you show your exact setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was one of the stranger bugs I've come across. For some reason, it appears 'tap to click' on my trackpad wasn't activating the switch. I tried 'press to click' and a USB mouse and both worked. It only occurs with switches on the simulator. Everything else activates, buttons, cells, etc.